# How well is a low level multithreading network application in C# going to work on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, multithreading, networking, mono

We are going to build a server application in C# with following properties and technologies:

- server-client model running on TCP/IP serving up to hundreds of clients at the same time
- multithreaded design with lots of synchronization
- simple local database based on SQLite or similar engine
- public key cryptography and TLS

My question is, whether we can expect that such a server application will work on Linux as well and whether it will perform well similarly to how it will perform on the Windows platform.

We are not aware of the limitations of Mono and that is where my question points to. Can we expect threads and synchro to work well in Mono on Linux? Can we expect TCP networking to work well in Mono on Linux? Database?

What are today's limitations of running your C# app in Mono? Does it just work, or are there problems? Is something even impossible? Or is it necessary to write some parts of the code separately for each platform?

Edit: Note that I am looking for experience of developers who worked with Mono. I'm mostly concerned about threads and synchro operations. I am not looking for facts and experience, not opinions.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Mono Docs](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/) and specifically the [application porting](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/application-portability/) section? There's even a section on [database access](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/). If you're not doing something Windows specific (i.e. sticking with just basic .NET library functionality), then you shouldn't have too many issues.

Comment: Yes I did, I am mostly concern about threads and synchronization on Linux and also about using libraries - i.e. to download something from NuGet and use it.

Comment: I can't see how this question is opinion-based, I am looking for facts and experience from developers who actually used Mono. I'm looking for answers whether threads are working on Linux in Mono as well as they are on Windows in .NET, same for other parts.

Comment: I didn't vote to close it, but it would probably be opinion based because you're asking for the experience of using a specific tool (which is an opinion). And why wouldn't threading work the same in Mono in Linux and Windows? That's kind of the point of Mono; with out any specific code posted, we can't tell you if your code will work as expected on both platforms unless you try it and have specific issues. If you're concerned about issues with Mono not discussed in the docs, you'll probably get an answer on the Programmers channel.

Comment: As long as you use managed code, there is no problem porting .net to mono on linux (so no problem with nuget packages). And as long as you rely on .net stuff that is supported by your mono release, including multithreading, networking and so on, there is also no problem. Just check what is and what is not ported to mono (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/).